# AWS CLI S3 : Stop/Terminate a running command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have 40k mp3 files in my bucket's root directory(mess!). I planned to move all these mp3 files into a folder inside my bucket. I figured out a way for doing this through [AWS S3 CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html).

I used a simple move command for moving my files, I tested this command on a small batch of files and it works fine:

aws s3 mv s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket/converted/audios/ --exclude "*" --include "*__converted.mp3" --recursive

**My Problem:**

When I ran this command in Windows CMD, it keeps on running(cursor is blinking and there is no output yet). I guess it is because of large number of files. I want to terminate this action.

So, how can I terminate this command which is running ?

After surfing through AWS CLI documentation I found the [Cancel command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/cancel-command.html). But this requires a command_id.

Am I going in the right direction ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) runs locally.

There is no **move** command on AWS. Instead, the CLI is gathering a list of files and is issuing individual **Copy** commands to copy files from their current Key to the desired Key (Key = full path of filename). It then deletes the source files.

So, just use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to stop the process.

(The Cancel command you linked is to stop a Systems Manager (SSM) job running on AWS. It is not related to work done by the AWS CLI.)

Answer (score 6):

CTRL+BREAK, as Ctrl+C did not work for me.

Comment: WIN11: to be precise, Ctrl+c for me first ran to the end, but then told me `cancelled: ctrl-c received`.
However this behavior is not very useful, I had to wait 30 minutes until a sync was finished, to then see that it didn't do anything.